# SQLiteException: no such table: USER (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id=? LIMIT 1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working on someone else code and I'm not very familiar with android sql data base 
On my another system it was working perfectly but when I clone and build it with this system suddenly crashes and shows this exception

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.theinnotech.mahmoole.Utilities.AppController: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: USER (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id=? LIMIT 1, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5685)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
                                                                           Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: USER (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id=? LIMIT 1, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1397)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1239)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1110)
                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                              at com.orm.SugarRecord.find(SugarRecord.java:201)
                                                                              at com.orm.SugarRecord.findById(SugarRecord.java:135)
                                                                              at net.theinnotech.mahmoole.Utilities.AppController.onCreate(AppController.java:67)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1028)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5666)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6531) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

I search around and added `SugarContext.init(this);` and also increase my version database in the Manifest file but nothing changed

Comment: Please check where your USER table is created. Based on error we can say User table is not created. It means the problem is in create. Please share your database code snippet

Comment: May be a letter-case problem, if not at the table's name, maybe at database' filename... (see: "OS error - 2:No such file or directory")